# Two interfaces have same method

Tags: c#, .net

```
Interface A
{
    int Add(int a,int b);
}

Interface B
{
    int Add(int a,int b);
}

Class D : A, B
{
    int Add(int a,int b)
    {
        return a+b;
    }
}
```

Code works fine and didn't produce any error.
Class D is using which interface's method?

Comment: Neither interface is providing an implementation.

Comment: Class D is using its own method. Interfaces has nothing to do with implementations.

Comment: Not sure the question makes sense. I think the question should be another way around - does D class implements both interfaces? And the answer is yes.

Comment: All you have to worry about is which *implementation* of the method is getting used.  Which is unambiguous, there is only one.

Answer (score 6):

Neither, since neither interface HAS a method, merely a method signature.  Your method in D implements the signature provided by both interfaces, so it works.

Remember, an interface merely specifies the signatures of methods that must exist in an implementation.

Comment: As an update you could implement the interface so you had both by implementing A.Add() and B.Add() and providing different functionality for both.

Comment: @Andrew true but, per CompuChip below, that would introduce the need to specify which method you were calling each and every time you wanted to call D.Add().

Answer (score 2):

Since method signatures are the same on both interfaces, and class D implements those methods (with a single function), then it doesn't really matter which interface that function implements, and thus compiler is happy.

However, you can have two different implementations specific for each interface by declaring functions as

```
class D : A, B
{
    int A.Add(int a, int b)
    {
    }

    int B.Add(int a, int b)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: But IIRC, you always have to specify which method to call then, i.e. you can't do `new D().Add(a, b)`, but you have to write `(new D() as A).Add(a, b)` or `(new D() as B).Add(a, b)`. More commonly you will implement one implicitly and one explicitly, like in the case of `Enumerable` and `Enumerable<T>`.

Comment: @CompuChip Correct, because when you do explicit interface implementations, you (by definition) have to be explicit which one you're trying to call, which means you have to call by interface reference rather than by class reference.  That is IF you want explicit implementations (you don't have to do those if need not be)...

Answer (score 1):

> Class D is using which interface's method?

Neither.  Interfaces don't have methods, they only define the method signatures which the implementations should have.  You're thinking of it backwards.

- D doesn't use A's or B's method.
- A uses D's method on any instance of A which has D as it's implementation.
- B uses D's method on any instance of B which has D as it's implementation.

D satisfies both interfaces A and B by providing that method.